# Completing Oauth without the use of threading

Tags: c#

I am not exactly sure how to explain this so I'll give it my best shot. 
Basically I have an application that connects to DropBox. One of the situations I have run into is with the registering process. At the moment during the registration process it connects to DropBox using the default browser, which it then requires the user to login and click allow app to use the service. In return you get a token which the app can use to connect to the service with. The problem I am having is getting the application to wait until the above process is completed. The only way I have figured out to get it to wait is to use system.threading(int). however if the person takes longer then the timeout then it fails to register properly.

I am hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction and get it to wait without the threading function. I was hoping I could use a if loop or something but i have no idea how to do that properly.

here is the actual Oauth code:

```
private static OAuthToken GetAccessToken()
    {
        string consumerKey = "*****";
        string consumerSecret = "****";
        var oauth = new OAuth();
        var requestToken = oauth.GetRequestToken(new Uri(DropboxRestApi.BaseUri), consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        var authorizeUri = oauth.GetAuthorizeUri(new Uri(DropboxRestApi.AuthorizeBaseUri), requestToken);
        Process.Start(authorizeUri.AbsoluteUri);
        return oauth.GetAccessToken(new Uri(DropboxRestApi.BaseUri), consumerKey, consumerSecret, requestToken);
    }
```

and here is the complete oauth function that is called when the registration button is clicked:

```
var accesstoken = GetAccessToken();
```

Comment: What library are you using for the OAuth stuff?

Comment: Dropbox.api and OauthProtocol

Comment: What's the library's name? Or where did you get the dll in other words?  i.e. where is that GetAccessToken function defined?

Comment: What is 'system.threading(int)'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the Async (asynchronous) version of their GetAccessToken call.  One that will call some function of yours when it is complete.

You could also loop until the information is ready, e.g.

```
while (dataIsNotReady()) {
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // sleep for a bit. this is bad, locks up entire thread maybe even application while it sleeps.  Make it shorter for less impact.
    // TODO add a "timeout", i.e. only try this for X amount of time before breaking out
}

// Now we data is ready let's go
```

**Update:**
Perhaps you are better off using a library that can do it async for you e.g. this Dropbox C# library: https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet

Comment: i ended up switching to dropnet. Thank you i didn't see that lib when I was looking last week